# GROUP BY day but for specific timestamp

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I want to group by day but time shouldn't be 00:00:00 to 23:59:59
It should be 22:00:00 (previuos day) to 21:59:59 (current day)

I have query:

```
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('day',"timecolumn") "DATE",
    COUNT(*) 
FROM "schemaname"."tablename"
WHERE
    TO_CHAR("timecolumn",'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN '20200301' AND '20200307'
GROUP BY "DATE";
```

This is giving me count split across 7 days.

**But this data is calculated as below:**

```
2020-03-01 00:00:00 to 2020-03-01 23:59:59
2020-03-02 00:00:00 to 2020-03-02 23:59:59
2020-03-03 00:00:00 to 2020-03-03 23:59:59
2020-03-04 00:00:00 to 2020-03-04 23:59:59
2020-03-05 00:00:00 to 2020-03-05 23:59:59
2020-03-06 00:00:00 to 2020-03-06 23:59:59
2020-03-07 00:00:00 to 2020-03-07 23:59:59
```

**Whereas, I need data split across as below:**

```
2020-02-29 22:00:00 to 2020-03-01 21:59:59
2020-03-01 22:00:00 to 2020-03-02 21:59:59
2020-03-02 22:00:00 to 2020-03-03 21:59:59
2020-03-03 22:00:00 to 2020-03-04 21:59:59
2020-03-04 22:00:00 to 2020-03-05 21:59:59
2020-03-05 22:00:00 to 2020-03-06 21:59:59
2020-03-06 22:00:00 to 2020-03-07 21:59:59
```

Comment: I mean you should apply different timezone to your "timecolumn"

Comment: `TO_CHAR("timecolumn",'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN '20200301' AND '20200307'` is better written as `timecolumn >= date '2020-03-01' and timecolumn <= date  '2020-03-07'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right, the `timecolumn` is datetime column stored it's value in UTC timezone.
For calculate desired results you should apply your timezone before (for example 'europe/rome'):

```
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('day', "timecolumn") "DATE",
    "timecolumn" at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'europe/rome',
    COUNT(*) 
FROM "schemaname"."tablename"
WHERE
    TO_CHAR(
        "timecolumn" at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'europe/rome',
        'YYYYMMDD'
    ) BETWEEN '20200301' AND '20200307'
GROUP BY "DATE";
```

Look different timezones [here](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-convert-utc-to-local-time-zone-in-postgresql/).

Comment: Yes, the data is stored in UTC.. but I want to manipulate/see data in SAST which is +2 hours. Eventually I need group by day (i.e. SAST day)

Hence I need to subtract 2 hours from that time column

Answer (score 0):

Guess what....
Worked like a charm :):):)
Thanks so much @Slava Rozhnev

I did some modification to the query you provided.. PSB

```
SELECT 
    DATE_TRUNC('day',"timecolumn" at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'sast') "DATE",
    COUNT(*) 
FROM "schemaname"."tablename"
     WHERE TO_CHAR("timecolumn" at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'sast', 'YYYYMMDD') BETWEEN '20200521' AND '20200526'
GROUP BY "DATE";
```